# Регулярные выражения, как устроены паттерны (шаблоны) в них

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, visual-studio

Задание: В данном текстовом файле удалить все слова, которые содержат хотя бы одну цифру.

Вот не получается написать паттерн (шаблон) для `Regex.Replace()`, не могу понять ту самую закономерность как эти шаблоны писать, как они работают. Пробовал так `@"\s\D(\D*)\d\D(\D+)\s"` и так `@"\s\D(\D*|$)[0-9*]\D(\D*|$)"` пробовал по-разному, но оно работает все равно не так как надо!

Пожалуйста, можете  помочь с этим заданием и объяснить как работают паттерны (шаблоны), ну или дать ссылку на какую-нибудь хорошую статью почитать по этой теме с примерами.

---

Например строка:

```
Ever4 day in elementary school in America beg54ins at 9.20 a.m. Children have cla324sses till 3.15 p.m.
```

Из нее нужно удалить такие слова как: `Ever4`, `beg54ins`, `cla324sses`, так как они содержат цифры. Да, я знаю что можно разбить строку на массив и через цикл прогнать и удалить не нужное! Но меня интересует можно ли это сделать через Регулярные выражения, если да, то как должен выглядеть шаблон?

Comment: Приведите пример текста и желаемый результат. Если у вас текст - это просто набор строк, разделённых пробелами, можно обойтись и без регулярных выражений.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Здравствуйте.  Ну вот например строка: Ever4 day in elementary school in America beg54ins at 9.20 a.m. Children have cla324sses till 3.15 p.m.    Из нее нужно удалить такие слова как: Ever4, beg54ins, cla324sses так как они содержат цифры. Да, я знаю что можно разбить строку на массив  и через цикл прогнать и  удалить не нужное! Но меня интересует можно ли это сделать через Регулярные выражения, если да, то как должен выглядеть шаблон?

Comment: @Alex примеры лучше приводить в самом вопросе, а не в комментарияx. под ваш пример подойдет такое выражение, `@"\b(\p{L}+\d+\p{L}*|\p{L}*\d+\p{L}+)\b"`.

Comment: `Regex.Replace(text, @"\s*\b(?=[^\W\d]*\d)[^\W\p{L}]*\p{L}\w*", "")`?

Comment: [tag:регулярные-выражения] на странице тега есть ссылки на материалы для изучения

Comment: Шаблоны работают, спасибо всем за помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Внимание**. Для тестирования регулярных выражений .NET использовать http://regex101.com нужно осторожно, так как данный сервис не поддерживает библиотеку регулярных выражений .NET. Посмотреть простые шаблоны в действии там можно, но гарантировать идентичную их работу в среде .NET невозможно (проверьте хотя бы `[\p{L}-[а-яА-ЯёЁ]]` (любая нерусская буква), или `\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))\)` (строка между круглых скобок с поддержкой вложенных скобок)).

Проверить на валидность регулярное выражение .NET можно на следующих веб-сайтах:

- [Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester)
- [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/)
- [Ultrapico Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) (отдельное приложение)

При изучении регулярных выражений **всегда обращайте внимание на то, для какой библиотеки регулярных выражений вам нужно написать шаблон**, так как **распространённое убеждение, что "регулярки всюду одинаковы" ложно**. Для изучения регулярных выражений .NET, обращайтесь к [документации Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).

Общая информация и ссылки есть также на [странице описания тега "регулярные выражения"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/info).

Чтобы удалить слова, состоящих из букв, цифр или символов `_` и в которых есть как минимум одна буква и одна цифра, вам нужно

```cs
\s*\b(?=[^\W\d]*\d)[^\W\p{L}]*\p{L}\w*
```

См. [пример работы выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs*%5cb%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%5cW%5cd%5d*%5cd%29%5b%5e%5cW%5cp%7bL%7d%5d*%5cp%7bL%7d%5cw*&i=Ever4+day+in+elementary+school+in+America+beg54ins+at+9.20+a.m.+Children+have+cla324sses+till+3.15+p.m.&r=).

*Подробности*:

- `\s*` - ноль и более пробельных символов
- `\b` - граница слова
- `(?=[^\W\d]*\d)` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который требует наличия ноля и более букв или символов нижнего подчёркивания и затем одной цифры сразу после текущей позиции в строке
- `[^\W\p{L}]*` - ноль и более цифр или символов нижнего подчёркивания
- `\p{L}` - одна буква
- `\w*` - ноль и более букв, цифр или символов нижнего подчёркивания.

[Пример кода на C#](https://ideone.com/nvPNDj):

```cs
var text = "Ever4 day in elementary school in America beg54ins at 9.20 a.m. Children have cla324sses till 3.15 p.m.";
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s*\b(?=[^\W\d]*\d)[^\W\p{L}]*\p{L}\w*", string.Empty).Trim();
Console.WriteLine(result); // => day in elementary school in America at 9.20 a.m. Children have till 3.15 p.m.
```

Answer (score 2):

По вашей логике сам паттерн будет таким - `@".*\d.*"`. "Любойсимвол Циферка Любойсимвол".

https://regex101.com/r/9xgSv1/1 Вот здесь можете проверить как это работает и поиграться.

Из хороших статей - первая в яндексе. https://habr.com/ru/post/545150/

Comment: Приведенный паттерн не подходит для решения задачи автора (см. комментарии под вопросом). Данный паттерн выдает совпадение на все предложение целиком